# is having two broadcast receivers valid in android?

Tags: android

i don't know if this is okay having two broadcast receivers in my android app. I separated them cause the one receiver with the boot_completed, it will do a different task and the other receiver with also do different task when they receive a broadcast.

```
      <receiver android:name=".Autostart">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name=".AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Yes of course that is ok

Answer (score 0):

That is perfectly valid you should always try to seperate your concerns which part of a good architecture/good design principles.